# Using bit.dev and react-native env, the build is giving error

Tags: react-native, bit.dev

I created two components in react-native, they are working fine in my dev environment, when I use bit compile and bit status, everything remains on track, no errors. But when i use bit build or bit tag, it starts giving me error
`Validation Error: Preset react-native not found.`

To counter this, I have added a new env extension that is using react-native and my components are using the env extension. I have overrided the jest config and added preset there. Nothing works. Any solution to this?

I have also confirmed that components are using the env extension only.
configured tester: teambit.defender/jest (Jest @ 27.5.1) I tried overriding this jest version, which I was unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, for this we have to add react-native as dev-dependecies in workspace.jsonc file. Bit does't pick from the package.json.

Comment: can you please show code examples ?